# Loading images into a Grid asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await

I'm developing a small application which will get RAW image files, convert them to low quality JPEG's then load those JPEG's as thumbnails into a Grid.

**My problem:** I am having issues with the UI getting blocked while the images are being converted. I am dynamically adding controls to host those images in the grid just after the conversion is taking place for each image. Also I am binding those images to my `Image` control's `Source` with my `ControlProperties` ViewModel in code-behind.

**My coding:**

Here I am creating a new instance of my `ControlProperties` view model and inside I am doing the image conversion at the `ImageSource`.

```
cp = new ControlProperties()
{
    ImageId = controlCount += 1, ImageSource = ThumbnailCreator.CreateThumbnail(imagePath)
};
```

**My question:**

Seeing as the images take a while to load, I am in need to get full control of my UI while they are being converted and added into my grid, but I am not getting it right at all. Can someone please help me with some advice or coding snippets to get me going please?

**My `ThumbnailCreator` class**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace SomeProjName
{
    public class ThumbnailCreator
    {
        private static string imageLocation;
        private static int currentImage;
        public static BitmapImage CreateThumbnail(string oldImagePath)
        {
            ConvertHighQualityRAWImage(oldImagePath);

            if (imageLocation != string.Empty && imageLocation != null)
                return OpenImage(imageLocation);
            else return null;
        }

        //Creates low quality JPG image from RAW image
        private static void ConvertHighQualityRAWImage(string oldImagePath)
        {

            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(oldImagePath));
            var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 17 };
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

            using (var filestream = new FileStream(GetImageLocation(), FileMode.Create))
                encoder.Save(filestream);

            image.UriSource = null;
            image.StreamSource = null;
            image = null;

            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }

        //Returns low quality JPG thumbnail to calling method
        private static BitmapImage OpenImage(string imagePath)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.DecodePixelWidth = 283;
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Relative);
            image.EndInit();

            DeleteImage();
            return image;
        }

        private static string GetImageLocation()
        { 
            imageLocation = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "thumbnails")).FullName + GetCurrentImage();
            return imageLocation;
        }

        private static string GetCurrentImage()
        {
            return "\\" + (currentImage += 1).ToString() + ".jpg";
        }

        private static void DeleteImage()
        {
            if (File.Exists(imageLocation))
                File.Delete(imageLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are the images "being converted"? How is the "convert" method defined?

Comment: @mm8 I've updated my question. Please see below.

Comment: You should call the ConvertHighQualityRAWImage method on a background thread. Where and how do you call it? It doesn't return any value.

Comment: @mm8 I run it on a background thread using `await Task.Run(() => { _my coding_ });` I just commented it out and gave the reason for why just below the coding snippet.

Comment: You make no sense. Show exactly how you call the ConvertHighQualityRAWImage method if you want any help. And please get rid of any unrelevant code snippets.

Comment: If you are happy making the code available, then upload it somewhere and I will take a look at it for you.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, could you post the code _how_ you use the loading method? There is no need for that UI creation code here it is completely irrelevant, it should have been in xaml.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Sorry, it's not supposed to be in XAML because I need it to be created dynamically :) Which loading method are you talking about? I will post my whole CreateThumbnail class.

Comment: Fair enough, for those purposes we use `DataTemplate`s etc but that's beside the point. What we want to see is how you get the pictures, how you assign them to the UI elements. For now on single thread please.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I updated my code :) I will post my code on where I assign my images to my UI elements as soon as I get home.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to save your thumbnails to file. Use a `MemoryStream` instead:

```
public class ThumbnailCreator
{
    public static BitmapImage CreateThumbnail(string imagePath)
    {
        BitmapFrame source;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            source = BitmapFrame.Create(
                stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }

        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 17 };
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));

        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;

            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 283;
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
        }

        bitmap.Freeze();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

The intermediate encoding and decoding pass doesn't even seem to be necessary, so you could simply write this:

```
public class ThumbnailCreator
{
    public static BitmapImage CreateThumbnail(string imagePath)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 283;
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
        }

        bitmap.Freeze();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

If you want to call the CreateThumbnail method asynchronously, use `Task.Run()`:

```
cp.ImageSource = await Task.Run(() => ThumbnailCreator.CreateThumbnail(fileName));
```

Comment: This works so much faster. Thank you very much Clemens!

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution:**

I just want to add this comment to Clemens solution. I also use the Garbage Collector to stop massive memory usage build-up when loading a lot of images. Here is the final method that I use to create the thumbnails.

```
public static BitmapImage CreateThumbnail(string imagePath)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 283;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    bitmap.Freeze();

    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    return bitmap;
}
```